# What is the difference between @"1.5" and @(1.5) while setting the value in NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

In iPhone project,

It was while I was while setting Value in dictionary,

```
NSMutableDictionary*dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dictionary setValue:@(2.8) forKey:@"Why"];
```

AND,

```
NSMutableDictionary*dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dictionary setValue:@"2.8" forKey:@"Why"];
```

My question is Why not @"2.5" and @(2.5) ?

Comment: Because the kern attribute expects a number and not a string?

Comment: My question is not about Attrbuted string? I do not know the difference between @"0.5", and @(0.5).

Comment: See [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) in the _Clang 4.0 documentation._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions, it would be better to have a single question.

But as to the difference,`@"2.5"` is an `NSString` where `@(2.5)` is an `NSNumber`. There is a big difference between textual and numeric data.

As for why you need an `NSNumber` and not `NSString` is obvious: the kerning is a numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

using the @() syntax you can box arbitrary C expressions. This makes it trivial to turn basic arithmetic calculations into `NSNumber` objects see below:

```
double x = 24.0;
NSNumber *result = @(x * .15);
NSLog(@"%.2f", [result doubleValue]);
```

You can also refer `NSNumber` object as @"" string but cant make calculations like above example. In your case both are acceptable but here calculation makes difference.

Comment: Ya, Vaibhav, you are right. But it is also about taking the value.

Comment: I am actually experiencing it in a NSAttributedString and it's attribute NSKerningAttributeName.

Comment: Hi, so actually  `NSAttributedString` object manages character strings and if we talk specifically about `NSKerningAttributeName`  must intend  to contain **`NSNumber` object containing a floating-point value** so i suggest to go with `@( )` box instead of `@" "` which is string oriented, consider ans if you got your point :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use

@"2.5" it's behave like a string

```
NSMutableDictionary*dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [dictionary setValue:@"2.8" forKey:@"Why"];;
  NSString *a =   [dictionary ValueforKey:@"Why"];
```

but when you use @(2.8) then it's behave like a NSNumber

```
NSMutableDictionary*dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [dictionary setValue:@(2.8) forKey:@"Why"];;
  NSNumber *a =   [dictionary ValueforKey:@"Why"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@(2.8) is a type of NSNumber.

@"2.8" is a type of NSString.

Both the type and value were different between there two.